# Отладчик не выдаёт исключений

Tags: c#

Отладчик не выдаёт предупреждений об исключениях в асинхронном методе, метод просто перестаёт выполнятся.

```
public async Task Test()
{
   List<string> a = null;
   a.Count;
   // и дальше код не выполняется
   MessageBox.Show("Сообщение").
}
```

Comment: Поток просто упал и все. Null pointer Exception

Comment: А при вызове оборачиваете в try/catch и делаете await?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, А это нормально, что он так делает?

Comment: [Exception handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Если ответ вам не нужен, вы запустили что то и бог ему в помощь. Нормально или нет задачи разные бывают.

Comment: Попросту представьте вы отдельным таском отправляет команды, если ответ вам не нужен то это одна задача. Если нужен какой бы то нибыл то другая. Нормально обе нормально по мне

Comment: А как вы вызываете этот метод? Ваша проблема за пределами показанного кода. Вы вызвали асинхронный метод, и ни где не ожидаете его завершения, следовательно исключение улетело в бездну.

Comment: @aepot, Вызываю из синхронного метода, вот так Test();

Comment: @AimonZ. для общего развития: если вызвать `Test().Result` или `Test.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, то ваше исключение вылезет наружу, а все потому что вызывающий метод в этом случае будет заблокирован до завершения работы `Test()`. А следовательно исключение будет возвращено в основной поток, и вы его увидите как обычное исключение. Такой способ вызова называется `sync-over-async`, и он крайне не рекомендуется к использованию, и опасен дедлоками и другими сюрпризами. Я вам просто рассказываю, что он существует, используйте осмысленно и с осторожностью.

Comment: @AimonZ. если вам не нужно ждать завершения метода, используйте подход `fire-and-forget` с `async void`, предложенный в ответе ниже. Все исключения будут отловлены там в `catch`. Кстати, когда вы отлаживаете программу, в студии внизу есть "консоль" `Output`, и те самые исключения можно увидеть там, даже если вы их не поймали, даже до того как вы написали этот вопрос, они там отображались. В эту консоль можно писать с помощью `Debug.WriteLine()`, очень полезно при отладке графических приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вызвать асинхронный метод *без ожидания*

```
Test();
// или
var task = Test();
```

то исключение не выбрасывается по следующей причине: неизвестно, где именно его нужно выбросить. Ведь после вызова этого метода выполнение кода ушло далеко вперёд. Могли вызваться многие другие методы, мог произойти выход из текущего метода и т. п. Следовательно, исключение могло бы быть выброшено в любом произвольном месте. Это намного затруднило бы отладку - пойди угадай, где его ждать в следующий раз.

И оборачивание вызова в try-catch совершенно ничего не даст.

Именно поэтому исключение, произошедшее внутри отдельного потока/задачи остаётся в нём до тех пор, пока не будет произведено явное получение результата или ожидание. Оно может быть выполнено одним из следующих способов:

```
await task
task.Wait()
task.Result
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

При этом, если внутри задачи произошло исключение, оно будет выброшено в этом месте. Это логично и понятно, где именно его ловить, где ставить try-catch.

Ссылка на документацию: [Exception handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так, оберните вызов в try catch

```
public async Task Test()
{
    ....
}

public async void doTest()
{
    try
    {
        await Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: try-catch совершенно не важен. Важно получение результата: await, Result и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для Fire-and-Forget это вполне вменяемое решение.